# Deriving data from a multivariate normal distribution according to a specific correlation matrix in r

Tags: r, simulation, correlation, normal-distribution, covariance-matrix

I derive data from a multivariate normal distribution. I created the correlation structure I wanted by the sigma matrix. Since I take the standard deviation as 1, I expect the Sigma matrix and correlation of Z matrix to be the same, but it is not the same. how do i solve this problem?  So, how can I derive data from the multivariate normal distribution according to the correlation matrix I want?

```
  blck1 <- c(1:8)
  blck2 <- c(9:20)
  pr <- seq(0.05, 0.01, length.out = 20)
  Sigma <- toeplitz(pr)

  #### Blok1 ###############
  pr_blck1 <- seq(0.7, 0.3, length.out = length(blck1))
  Sigma_blck1 <- toeplitz(pr_blck1)
  Sigma[blck1, blck1] <-  Sigma_blck1
  diag(Sigma) <- 1
  
 Z <- rmvnorm(n= 50, 
               mean  = rep(0, 20), 
               sigma = Sigma )
 
Sigma
cor(Z)
```

Comment: I don't know if you've done this correctly, but to check if two correlations are the same, you need to have `Z` come from a very large `n`. If I use `n = 500e3`, then I get:
`> mean((Sigma - cor(Z))**2)
[1] 1.889569e-06
`

Comment: thank you for the answer. I actually want to have correlations between the variables in the order I determine. I'm not interested in mean correlation or error. What I want to do here is that block1 should be moderately-highly correlated in itself, and block 2 should be low-correlated within itself and with block 1. However, I could not find such an arrangement.